# How to Pause and Resume Downloading Files with ASIHTTP Request in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I m using ASIHTTP Request sample source code for downloading urls.
My question is that how to pause and resume the downloading files.

Please Help.

Comment: you can see [this](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) document which shows all instruction to use ASIHTTP Request.

Comment: Thanks for reply dude,I read the instruction but there in no instruction for pausing download....

Answer (score 4):

### Deprecation Notice

ASIHTTP was deprecated around 2011, if you want network connectivity now, you should look up [AFNetworking for ObjC](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [Alamofire for Swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), or stick to the native support:

For native support, in iOS 7 Apple added the `NSURLSession`, which can start download tasks (`NSURLSessionDownloadTask`), and these can be cancelled and restarted, check the method  `downloadTaskWithResumeData(_:)` from `NSURLSession`, that has a very good explanation.

ASIHTTP is no longer needed, if you gotta are keeping a legacy app running, well, good luck.

### Original Answer

*Posted on 2011*

ASI itself can resume a download from a file using `[myASIRequest setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];`, check out the [How-to-Use](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#resuming_interrupted_downloads) for an example.

Edit: Ok, there's no easy way to pause a download (a `[myRequest pause]` would be ideal). After reading and trying for a while, turns out that cancelling the request and resending it again is the only way.

For example, here's an example class I made:

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>
{
    ASIHTTPRequest *requestImage;
    UIImageView *imageViewDownload;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewDownload;

- (IBAction)didPressPauseButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)didPressResumeButton:(id)sender;
```

To start (or restart) the download:

```
- (IBAction)didPressResumeButton:(id)sender
{
    if (requestImage)
        return;
    
    NSLog(@"Resumed");
    
    // Request
    requestImage = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myheadhealth.com/_IMAGES/cheese.jpg"]];
    
    // Using a temporary destination path just for show. 
    // Better pick a suitable path for your download.
    NSString *destinationDownloadPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cheese.jpg"];
    NSString *temporaryDownloadPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cheese.jpg-part"];
    
    requestImage.downloadDestinationPath = destinationDownloadPath;
    requestImage.temporaryFileDownloadPath = temporaryDownloadPath;
    requestImage.allowResumeForFileDownloads = YES;
    requestImage.delegate = self;
    [requestImage startAsynchronous];
}
```

In the exmaple above, I'm loading a random image of cheese I found, and storing a temporary download, and a full download.

Canceling the request will keep the contents of the temporary file intact, in fact, I made an UIImageView, and when pressing "Cancel" I could see a part of the downloaded file. If you want to try it out:

```
- (void)didPressPauseButton:(id)sender
{
    if (requestImage)
    {
        // An imageView I made to check out the contents of the temporary file.
        imageViewDownload.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:requestImage.temporaryFileDownloadPath];
        
        [requestImage clearDelegatesAndCancel];
        requestImage = nil;
        
        NSLog(@"Canceled");
    }
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    imageViewDownload.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:request.downloadDestinationPath];
    
    requestImage = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply,please help for pausing download files

Comment: Hey, I have used this code but got error like BAD_EXCESS.. It gives on this line only.. [request clearDelegatesAndCancel]; Also gives warning this instant method not found, Please help me this issue.. Thanks..

Comment: I added a bit more code from my example. Your `BAD_ACCESS` probably occurs because you pressed the button after the request finished, I edited my code so it would set the `requestImage` to `nil` to prevent that. 

Notice that the code I posted originally was meant as an example, not for copy-pasting.